# <c:forEach> or <ui:repeat> not access <p:dataTable var>, is there other solution ?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am working with jsf Mojarra 2.2.7, Java 8, Primefaces 6.0

I have a class MeasurmentRecording. The class MeasurementRecording has a List with DoubleRecordings. I can't access the p:datatable var "tempMeasurementRecording" in the the c:foreach part for showing the doubleRecordings. With ui:repeat it's the same problem. I know that i can't access  the p datatable var because of view and build Time of JSF.

But what solution do I have to fix this problem ? (Back or Frontend).

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl"
    value="#{measurementRecordingLazyDataActions.measurementRecordings}"
    var="tempMeasurementRecording"
    rowKey="#{tempMeasurementRecording.measurementRecordingID}"
    widgetVar="#{tableConsts.widgetVar}"
    tableStyleClass="#{tableConsts.tableStyleClass}"
    rows="#{tableConsts.rows}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="#{tableConsts.rowsPerPageTemplate}"
    resizableColumns="#{tableConsts.resizableColumns}"
    scrollable="true" scrollHeight="470" lazy="true">


    <f:facet name="{Exporters}">
        <h:commandLink>
            <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" />
            <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tbl"
                fileName="measurementrecording" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </f:facet>

    <c:forEach
        items="#{tempMeasurementRecording.doubleRecordingComponents}"
        var="doubleRecordingComponent">
        <p:column
            headerText="#{doubleRecordingComponent.minMaxComponent.name}"
            filterBy="#{doubleRecordingComponent.value}">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{doubleRecordingComponent.value}"
                        title="#{doubleRecordingComponent.value}">
                        <f:converter converterId="decimalNumberConverter" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText styleClass="#{tableConsts.errorClass}"
                        value="#{doubleRecordingComponent.value}"
                        style="width:100%"
                        label="#{doubleRecordingComponent.value}">
                        <f:converter converterId="decimalNumberConverter" />
                    </h:inputText>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column
            headerText="#{doubleRecordingComponent.minMaxComponent.name}"
            filterBy="#{doubleRecordingComponent.minMaxComponent.min}">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{doubleRecordingComponent.minMaxComponent.min}"
                        title="#{doubleRecordingComponent.minMaxComponent.min}">
                        <f:converter converterId="decimalNumberConverter" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText styleClass="#{tableConsts.errorClass}"
                        value="#{doubleRecordingComponent.minMaxComponent.min}"
                        style="width:100%"
                        label="#{doubleRecordingComponent.minMaxComponent.min}">
                        <f:converter converterId="decimalNumberConverter" />
                    </h:inputText>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

    </c:forEach>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: If you **know** why `c:foreach` does not work, why do you ask? Stating that earlier in you question helps btw, I already created a comment that pointed to a jstl im jsf answer

Comment: I ask if there is an other solution to show the datatable. Because of accessing the var of datatable doesn't work. Where is your comment ? Can you link it?

Comment: Accessing the var of the datatable does work... Only not in the way you want it (cannot find a duplicate of your Q but there is). Think of it, the number of columns you want to show per row are dependent of the current row. That is simply not possible, not in any way. How would that look like? Just create a different model in your backend and use the `p:colums`